# Correct design in Django to handle forms and views depending on the type of user

Tags: python, django

## Problem

I'm writing an application in Django that connects students with tutors. There are three main models: `Student`, `Tutor`, and `Coordinator`.

The problem is that the website in itself is pretty similar for all three types of models, but each varies a bit on what they actually get to do or see.

For instance, all three types of user can book a class via the `BookClassForm`. However, the `Coordinator` can assign a tutor and student, while a tutor and student cannot. Or for example a `Coordinator` can see all the classes from all students and tutors on the calendar view, while a student only sees *his* classes.

In general does this mean I should write three separate forms or one form that makes some inputs optional for each type of user? Do I write three templates or one template where I put the logic for each type of user? Do I write three views that handle each type of user or one main view? Do I write three apps for each type of user or one main app?

I'm ending up with this really big application with a lot of views and repetitive code and I don't really know what the correct course of action is.

---

I've tried a few options to solve this as clean as I can:

## Option 1

The first option is pretty naive, I maintain only one `urls.py` file and do the logic on the view. Something along the lines of:

```py
# views.py
def classes_view(request):
   if request.user.is_superuser:
     # a coordinator
     return render(request, "classes.html", {'classes': Class.objects.all()})
   try:
      if request.user.tutor:
        return render(request, "classes.html", {'classes': Class.objects.filter(tutor=request.user.tutor))
    except Tutor.DoesNotExist:
        return render(request, "classes.html", {'classes': Class.objects.filter(student=request.user.student))
```

The problem is I'm writing this boilerplate code on dozens of views.

## Option 2

Divide the project into three apps (student, tutor, coordinator) and handle the views separately. I'm afraid this option will lead to a lot of code duplication, but I might be wrong. Another inconvenience I see is what happens when the three apps want to interact with a fourth common app?

Say for instance I create a `notifications` app that handles all the logic and models for notifications in the application. It would have a `urls.py` like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'delete-notification/(?P<pk>\d+)$', NotificationDelete.as_view(), name='delete-notification'),
    url(r'notification/(?P<pk>\d+)$', NotificationView.as_view(), name='notifications'),
]
```

Now if I want to hook it up to both a coordinator and student, I would need to add to both the following:

```py
# coordinator/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^notifications/', include('notifications.urls')),
    url(r'^tutors/', TutorsView.as_view(), name='tutors'),
]

# student/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^notifications/', include('notifications.urls')),
    url(r'^my-classes/', ClassesView.as_view(), name='classes'),
]
```

But then what if I want to add logic **inside** the notifications app that depends on the type of user? What if I want to soft delete notifications for `Coordinator`s and hard delete notifications for `Student`s? Where would I put the logic there? I feel like the notifications app is independent in a way of all of this.

---

I don't know, I'm very confused.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.